# Display the image used as launch image fullscreend as background

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to show the image that is used as launch image as background and as fade between launch and first view.
I "select" the image I want to use as follows:

```
NSString *defaultImageName = @"Default.png";
CGFloat imageScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size;
if (imageScale > 1) {
    if (imageSize.height < 500) {
        defaultImageName = @"Default@2x.png";
    } else {
        defaultImageName = @"Default-568h@2x.png";
    }
}
backimg = [UIImage imageNamed:defaultImageName];
UIImageView *backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: backimg];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundImage];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImage];
```

Sadly the image isn´t shown fullscreen, it is display scaled:
[image: wrong]

instead of

[image: correct]

Can anyone help with that?

**Update #1:**
solved using `[backgroundImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width , self.view.frame.size.height)];`

Comment: what size are your source images?

Comment: @how did you solve this?

Comment: @user2526811 by now I am using image assets in Xcode which "automatically" do the naming for me, I only have to specify the image asset I want to use and the OS does the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create the image view and set the frame to fill up the entire screen.
2. Set the imageView's image
3. Set the imageView's `contentMode` to center.

You don't need to have an if statement to determine the image to use. Just use `[UIImage imageNamed: @"Default"]`. Having the `@2x` and the `-568h` is enough for UIImage to use the correct file.

Comment: i finally stumbled upon the "trick" setting the bound of my view - but thanks anyway :)
and since you pointed out the same solution, up and accept.
Your edit seems nearly to awesome to work ^^

Answer (score 0):

Get Image use

```
[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                           pathForResource:@"xxx" ofType:@"png"]]
```

Instead of

```
[UIImage imageNamed: @"xxx"]
```